# How to avoid escape character "\" in PDO prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT ac.id AS target_id FROM account AS ac JOIN 
               address_vod__c AS ad 
               ON (ad.account_vod__c = ac.id AND ad.primary_vod__c = 1)  
               WHERE ac.id IN (?)";
```

And I am trying to add values for `IN` clause from a array as follow:

```
// $values is a huge array containing values

$params = [implode("','", $values)];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Code is working but I am getting the wrong SQL:

```
SELECT 
    ac.id AS target_id
FROM
    account AS ac
        JOIN
    address_vod__c AS ad ON (ad.account_vod__c = ac.id
        AND ad.primary_vod__c = 1)
WHERE
    ac.id IN ('00180000017rkSfAAI\',\'0018000001GgXTtAAN\',\'0018000001GgXTYAA3')
```

I expect and I am looking something like:

```
SELECT 
    ac.id AS target_id
FROM
    account AS ac
        JOIN
    address_vod__c AS ad ON (ad.account_vod__c = ac.id
        AND ad.primary_vod__c = 1)
WHERE
    ac.id IN ('00180000017rkSfAAI','0018000001GgXTtAAN','0018000001GgXTYAA3')
```

How do I avoid PDO from escape the strings?

Comment: You are putting your entire string in one value.  You need to have one `?` for each value that you're using.  You'll need to have `IN(?,?,?)` and bind your three values separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `ac.id IN (?)`.  This is telling the database that you want to bind *one* parameter to the query.  If you have multiple elements, you need multiple `?`s: `ac.id IN (?,?,?)`.

What you can do is *dynamically* add the `?`s and then bind each parameter that you need.

```
$params = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?'));
$sql = "SELECT ac.id AS target_id FROM account AS ac
    JOIN address_vod__c AS ad ON (ad.account_vod__c = ac.id AND ad.primary_vod__c = 1)
    WHERE ac.id IN ({$params})";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($values);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implode the placeholders and let pdo do the work

```
$inArray = array_fill(0, count($values), '?');
$inExpr = implode(',', $inArray);
$sql = "... WHERE id IN ($inExpr)";
```

And then just pass $values - pdo will do the rest for you